# How can I mount a second disk to a Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mount, docker-build, mount-point

I have a Docker container on Ubuntu.  This container uses a PCIe drive and I want to add a SATA drive.  Neither drive should share data with other containers.

How can I do this?

From the command `docker run`?
Or through the Dockerfile?

Here's the lsblk on the server:

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 744.7G  0 disk
|-sda1        8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
|-sda2        8:2    0     1K  0 part
|-sda5        8:5    0   976M  0 part
`-sda6        8:6    0 743.5G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0 349.3G  0 disk
`-nvme0n1p1 259:2    0 349.3G  0 part /media/pcie-disk
```

Here's the lsblk on the Docker container:

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 744.7G  0 disk
|-sda1        8:1    0   243M  0 part
|-sda2        8:2    0     1K  0 part
|-sda5        8:5    0   976M  0 part
`-sda6        8:6    0 743.5G  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0 349.3G  0 disk
`-nvme0n1p1 259:2    0 349.3G  0 part /etc/hosts
```

Comment: How are you using the PCIe drive in the container? A [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PCIe in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the disk to your host at any endpoint, then mount the endpoint to the Docker container as one of its volumes.

Comment: this does not a work. A volume is exposed as a mountpoint, not as a disk in /dev